# Random outputs on a program that checks if a number is perfect

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a program that checks if the numbers inside an array are perfect numbers. The program kinda works. It correctly checks and outputs if the numbers in the array are perfect. But there is one problem that I don't understand at all. The program checks and outputs a seemingly random amount of random numbers.

Here's the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numbers[6] = {45, 6, 789, 28, 43, 496};

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(numbers); i++){
        int sum = 0;
            for(int j = 1; j < numbers[i]; j++){
                if(numbers[i] % j == 0)
                    sum += j;
        }
        if(sum == numbers[i])
            cout << numbers[i] << " is a perfect number" << endl;
        else
            cout << numbers[i] << " is not a perfect number" << endl;
    }

    system("pause>0");
}
```

And here's the output (together with the "random" numbers):

```
45 is not a perfect number
6 is a perfect number
789 is not a perfect number
28 is a perfect number
43 is not a perfect number
496 is a perfect number

// Where the random numbers start to appear

0 is a perfect number
0 is a perfect number
0 is a perfect number
0 is a perfect number
1216376645 is not a perfect number
32682 is not a perfect number
0 is a perfect number
0 is a perfect number
421388600 is not a perfect number
32767 is not a perfect number
0 is a perfect number
1 is not a perfect number
4196646 is not a perfect number
0 is a perfect number
0 is a perfect number
0 is a perfect number
1815038419 is not a perfect number
500691909 is not a perfect number
```

Thanks for your attention. I’m looking forward to your reply.

Comment: What is the perfect number you mentioned there?? Just asking out of curiosity

Comment: Try printing out what `sizeof(numbers)` is and see if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(numbers)` returns the *number of bytes* of the array `numbers`.

You should divide that with the size of one element like `sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(*numbers)` to obtain the number of elements.

Comment: Even better: Since this is C++, we can use [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which has a `.size()` method.

Comment: or just use vectors. They are much better than arrays

Comment: Worked perfectly! Also, thanks for the information. Never knew that sizeof()  returned the number of bytes.

Comment: Note also that you can use [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) with C-arrays as well.